# Working functionality of user authentication in LDAP

Tags: ldap

I am studying ldap from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol), [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) and from [openldap pdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol).

But, the user authentication method and user search method is not clear to me. I tried to get details on from google but found nothing useful.

I came to know about the keyword 'filter' used with ldap_search() function in php but not sure what should be the value of it.

Can anyone explain how user authentication works in ldap and also how it performs search function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### BIND (authenticate) Operation

When an LDAP client connects to an LDAP server, the connection state is *unauthenticated*. LDAP clients request that the authorization state of the connection be changed with a BIND request. When the LDAP server receives the BIND request, the connection is immediately transitioned to the unauthenticated state. If the BIND request was successful, the server transitions the authorization state of the connection to that state associated with the distinguished name presented in the BIND request, otherwise the authorization state remains unauthenticated.

#### SEARCH Operation

The LDAP search operation is used to retrieve entries, and optionally their attributes from the database hosted by an LDAP server. To use the search operation, the LDAP client must connect to the server, optionally authenticate to the server using the BIND operation, and transmit a search request containing at a minimum, the following parameters:

- base object - the object above which no entries are returned
- scope - the scope of the search, either base, one, or subtree
- filter - a filter which narrows the list of candidate entries to just the entries desired by the LDAP client
- a list of attributes to return with the search result

Entries and their attributes are protected by access controls, so it is best, and sometimes required, to authenticate using the BIND operation before issuing a search request.

Search results can be successful but return no entries.

It is best practice to also provide a time limit and a size limit to the search operation. The LDAP server will return a search result which contains a result code indicating the success or failure of the search request and possibly a list of entries or references which match the search request parameters.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: A quick question. Is ldap_search() function executed during the user authentication process?

Comment: Probably not. As I noted in my answer, BIND and SEARCH are entirely separate operations. An API that combined the two would be a very poorly designed, so I doubt `ldap_search` authenticates.